# jQuery .serialize() does not work properly in angular

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I am working in form where I want to post all fields via jQuery .serialize() function but when I alert my serialized object it only alerts the keys and won't show the values against key.

Here is my angular script.

```
 app.controller('myForm',function($http,$scope){

    $scope.mydata=$('#myform').serialize();

    $scope.saveCashbook=function()
    {
        alert(this.mydata);
      $http({
        method: "POST",
        url: 'cashbook/save_cash_entry',
        data: this.mydata,
      }).success(function (data) {
        if (data.status == 'success') {
          alert('all okay');
        } else {
          alert(data.msg)
        }
      });
    }

 });
```

**Where as its work properly in jquery**

```
$('#submit').click(function(event) {
    var mydata=$('#myform').serialize();
    alert(mydata);
});
```

Please sort me out where I am committing mistake.

Comment: Which is the result of the call `$('#myform').serialize()`?

Comment: Why does not use the ng-model attribute on your input forms something like mydata.input1, mydata.input2 and so on. then simply pass the data using the variable mydata without use the serialize method from jQuery?

Comment: i am new to angular thats why i use this approach cause i am fimiliar with jquery

Comment: if i use ng-model how can i serialize array than like .serialize() function

Comment: In that case read any tutorial that you found example this https://scotch.io/tutorials/submitting-ajax-forms-the-angularjs-way

Comment: @rkmax it just give me the whole form fields with there values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have done it using the following code... Serialize work for me the main thing is header to give info  `headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }`

```
 app.controller('myForm',function($http,$scope){

    $scope.saveCashbook=function()
    {

      $http({
        method: "POST",
        url: 'cashbook/save_cash_entry',
        data: $('#supplier_form').serialize(),
        headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
      }).success(function (data) {
        if (data.status == 'success') {
          alert('all okay');
        } else {
          alert(data)
        }
      });
    }

 });
```

Answer (score 1):

How to send a form using angular no jQuery required

If the call expects a object like this

```
{
  firstName: "Julian",
  lastName: "Reyes Escrigas"
}
```

And your html form is like this

```
<form>
  <label for="firstName">First name</label>
  <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" />

  <label for="lastName">Last name</label>
  <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" />

  <input type="submit" value="Process" />
</form>
```

On your javascript side will be something like

```
function dataController($http) {

  var vm = this;

  vm.myData = {};    

  vm.submit = function() {
    $http({method: 'POST', url: '/endpoint', data: vm.myData})
    .then(/*...*/)
    .catch(/*...*/);
  }
}

app.controller('dataController', ['$http', dataController]);
```

now update your template to something like this

```
<form ng-controller="dataController as ctrl" ng-submit="ctrl.submit()" >
  <label for="firstName">First name</label>
  <input type="text" name="firstName" ng-model="ctrl.myData.firstName" id="firstName" />

  <label for="lastName">Last name</label>
  <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" ng-model="ctrl.myData.lastName"/>

  <input type="submit" value="Process" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use angular.element('#myForm').serialize();

Quote from [angular.element documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element):

> If jQuery is available, angular.element is an alias for the jQuery function. If jQuery is not available, angular.element delegates to Angular's built-in subset of jQuery, called "jQuery lite" or jqLite.

And 2 things i want to say after reviewing your code.

1: Always add "Ctrl" after your controller name, this is a best practice when working within a team because it makes your code more readable.

2: Change your .success() callback to this

```
.success(function (data) {
      alert(data.msg);
      }
.catch(function(err) {
      alert(err);
      };
```

The reason for this is because the .success() callback ONLY gets run if the $http was successful.

This means that the if-statement was of no use.

the `.catch()` catches the err if an error occurs.

Best of luck!

Comment: i am checking this up buddy

Comment: yeah i have solved one error but get into another one